# I need to master VPS management

Tags: vps, installation

We're looking at buying a VPS here to do all our hosting from. The company we're looking at buying it from offers cPanel to perform management on it.

What I'm after is some good reading material on how to manage a VPS. Setting up jails/guest OS's (what ever they're referred to), managing IP's, etc...

I imagine this kind of stuff can all be achieved via cPanel. But it'd be nice to know how to SSH into the root OS and perform all the admin tasks.

What's some good VPS management e-books/tutorials/how-to's etc. I can read?

Answer (score 2):

At the point you're talking about, you want more of a "How to administer a Linux Server", since that's what you're doing.

CPanel, Webmin, and all of those types of tools are abstraction layers that you're dispensing with. When you go below those, it's core administration, which means learning to fiddle with the knobs of the various softwares running the show. This includes things like your MTA (sendmail or postfix, probably), your web server (probably Apache, though maybe nginx), the interpreted scripting language (php or maybe perl), plus all of the other fun bits that come with server administration that you mentioned, like user administration, network configuration, storage management, manual backups, etc etc.

Does it sound like fun? If so, you're a sick person (and welcome to the club).

I would recommend a general purpose Linux admin book. If you've got a CentOS OS installed, you could do a lot worse than Red Hat Linux Unleashed (Redhat and CentOS are essentially identical, for the tasks you'll be accomplishing). There are equivalent books for whatever OS you end up with, so do a search on Amazon. If you update with the distro you're running, I'm willing to bet that some people could offer good suggestions.

It's a big can of worms that you're talking about opening. Make sure you're really interested before you dig in. The rabbit hole is deep.

Comment: I've setup networking and standard Linux web servers before. That's no problem. Apache, PHP, MySQL, etc... It's setting up multiple operating systems on top of the root machine that seems odd. I know freebsd can run jails. But from my understanding, VPS's generally run Virtual Machines in order to run multiple operating systems? This is the kind of stuff that seems hard

Comment: +1 - exactally what i started to write, but i've spent too much time at the mad hatter's tea party today

Comment: @peak: With VPS's you are getting the Virtual machine. You don't do any management as far as VM allocations, etc. What you see is a "guest OS" your provider is the one who has to worry about VM Management.

Comment: So with my VPS, all I'd really be doing is setting up apache vhosts for websites (for example)? How does multiple IP's come into this then?

Comment: @peak: Zypher is right. Don't confuse the VM host (the server running the VM) with the VM guest (which is what your VPS will be). If you want to run your own VPSes, you'll need a physical piece of hardware, or rent a dedicated server

Comment: @peak: If you need multiple IPs, you'll need to setup aliases for your interface, like eth0:1 and so on. After that, you just make sure that apache is listening on *:80 and configure your virtual hosts as necessary. It isn't necessary to run one vhost to one IP if you use name virtual hosts. http://www.ghacks.net/2009/03/17/adding-a-name-based-virtual-host-in-apache/